# Creating table with two fields that are unique both way

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I'm trying to make a table with two fields (id1, id2) where they are both referencing id as foreign key in some other table and are unique both ways.

Quick example:

Table 'people' that has fields id and name. Table 'marriage' that has fields id1 and id2. Now if I know that someone with id=3 is married to id=6 then there's no need to have (id1=3, id2=6) and (id1=6, id2=3) in 'marriage' table.

Comment: what is the question ? Go ahead and create the table !

Comment: Is there a way to do it with constraints? That is the question

Comment: yes. In mysql you can use foreign keys constraints. That will fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Just use  `FOREIGN KEY` and link them with `REFERENCES` like this:
`CREATE TABLE Marriage (
    MarriageID int NOT NULL,
    PersonAID int,
    PersonBID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonAID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonBID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);`

Comment: There's no harm in storing both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this with a `check` constraint.  Something like:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_id1_id2 check (id1 < id2)
```

Or, a unique index, using expressions or computed columns:

```
create unique index unq_t_id1_id2 on (least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2));
```

The most recent version of MySQL supported generated columns, so you can do something similar to the above with generated columns.

Otherwise, you need to use a trigger.  That is definitely doable, but you need to take logic into account both for inserts and updates.  Triggers are more work than constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key constraint.. here is the way to do it using query

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```